# How to inherit and chain String without polluting String.prototype?

Tags: javascript, string, inheritance, prototype, chaining

What I want to be able to do is something like this:

```
var where = new Where();
where('a'); // returns a string 'WHERE a' that I can chain against

where('a').andWhere('b'); // reuturns 'WHERE a AND b' that is also chainable

where('a').andWhere('b').orWhere('c'); // 'WHERE a AND b OR c', and so on ...
```

The where methods should return what is for all intents and purposes a string, with all string like methods, but with the two custom `andWhere` and `orWhere` methods.

When I tried inheriting from Sting.prototype, my where methods returned an object, not a string. Of course, if I returned a string directly from the methods, they didn't have the `andWhere` and `orWhere` methods, so chaining broke.

The code below does what I want, but it does it by polluting the String.prototype. Is there a way to get the same behavior, but encapsulated in a custom object?

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "andWhere", {
  value: function _andWhere(clause) {
    return [this, 'AND', clause].join(' ');
  },
  configurable: true,
  enumerable: false,
  writeable: true
});

Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "orWhere", {
  value: function _orWhere(clause) {
    return [this, 'OR', clause].join(' ');
  },
  configurable: true,
  enumerable: false,
  writeable: true
});


function where(clause){
  return ['WHERE', clause].join(' ');
}

where('a').andWhere('b').orWhere('c');
// => 'WHERE a AND b OR c'
```

Edit

I still want to have access to all the string methods off the object directly. In other words the returned object acts just like a string, but with a couple more methods. For example:

```
var whereStr = where('a').andWhere('b').orWhere('c');
whereStr.length; // => 18
whereStr.concat(' and so on'); // => 'WHERE a AND b OR c and so on'
```

If it makes any difference, this is primarily for Node, but ideally would work for any recent (ES5) javascript implementation. Again, this works perfectly if I'm bad and use String.prototype, I'm hoping there's a way to do a drop in replacement.

Comment: You're already defining some object-y stuff, so why not make an object prototype that handles this chaining and then override toString()?

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATED** Added in an example of creating the length property as a "getter".

```
function Where(conditional) {
    var thisObj = this;

    //Setup the length property's "getter"
    this.__defineGetter__( "length", function() {
        return thisObj.clause.length;
    });

    this.start( conditional );
}

Where.prototype = {
    AND_STR: " AND ",
    OR_STR: " OR ",
    add: function(conditional, prefix) {
        this.clause += prefix + conditional;
    },
    and: function(conditional) {
        this.add( conditional, this.AND_STR ); 
        return this;
    },
    or: function(conditional) { 
        this.add( conditional, this.OR_STR ); 
        return this;
    },
    start: function(conditional) {
        this.clause = "WHERE " + conditional;
    },
    toString: function() {
        return this.clause;
    }
}

//Use it like this (this shows the length of the where statement):
alert( new Where( "a" ).and( "b" ).or( "c" ).length );
```

Comment: Thanks, this very nice. The only thing I'm hoping to improve on is to have the string methods directly on the Where object. With this approach the returned object doesn't have any string property/methods (e.g.: length, concat, etc). I realize I can use .clause to get access to the internal string but I'd prefer to avoid that if possible.  Is there an easy way to include the String methods into the Where prototype?

Comment: @forforf yes, you define those as setters/getters: http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/ See my updated code for an example using `length`. (If this is correct, please mark it as the answer)

Comment: I didn't accept this answer because it's not a drop in replacement for  a string. I'd have to manually copy every method over, and if String.prototype got extended, those extensions would not be available. I did vote it up because I did find it useful, even if it's not quite what I need.